# Detect changes in NSArray in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, hash, nsarray

I need to detect change in NSArray object - that is if some object was added/removed to/from NSArray or was just edited in-place. Are there some integrated NSArray hash functions for this task - or I need to write my own hashing function for NSArray ? Maybe someone has different solution ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `NSArrayController`, which is [Key-Value-Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) compliant. Unfortunately `NSArray` is only KVC compliant. This way you can easily monitor the array controller's `arrangedObjects` property. This should solve your problem.

Also, see this question: [Key-Value-Observing a to-many relationship in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477204/key-value-observing-a-to-many-relationship-in-cocoa)

Comment: This will not tell you if an object is mutated while in the array, though. You'd need to observe every single element in the array.

Answer (score 6):

All objects have a `-hash` method but not all objects have a good implementation.

NSArray's documentation doesn't define it's result, but testing reveals it returns the length of the array - not very useful:

```
NSLog(@"%lu", @[@"foo"].hash);              // output: 1
NSLog(@"%lu", @[@"foo", @"bar"].hash);      // output: 2
NSLog(@"%lu", @[@"hello", @"world"].hash);  // output: 2
```

If performance isn't critical, and if the array contains `<NSCoding>` objects then you can simply serialise the array to `NSData` which has a good `-hash` implementation:

```
[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:@[@"foo"]].hash             // 194519622
[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:@[@"foo", @"bar"]].hash     // 123459814
[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:@[@"hello", @"world"]].hash // 215474591
```

For better performance there should be an answer somewhere explaining how to write your own `-hash` method. Basically call `-hash` on every object in the array (assuming the array contains objects that can be hashed reliably) and combine each together mixed in with some simple randomising math.